# How to detect an error in mapreduce

Tags: mongodb

Let's have an "error_test.js" file that contains:

```
db = db.getMongo().getDB( "mydb" );
db.mycol.insert( { hello : "world" } );


print("it is shown");
db.runCommand(
               {
                 mapReduce:  "mycol",
                 map:        function(){ print(not_exists); },
                 reduce:     function(key, values){},
                 out:        { replace: "myrescol" }
               }
             );
print("it is shown too (after error in mapreduce!)");
```

If I run the file (in Windows command line), I get:

```
mypath>mongo error_test.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.0
connecting to: test
it is shown
it is shown too (after error in mapreduce!)

mypath>echo %errorlevel%
0

mypath>
```

So we can deduce that:

- the mapreduce error doesn't stop the execution.
- the mapreduce error is not shown to the user.
- the mapreduce error is not translated to the exit code (0 = success) (so a caller program can't detect the error).

The only way to know of the error is by looking for the following line at "mongod.log":

```
Wed Jun 12 10:02:37.393 [conn14] JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: not_exists is not defined near '(){ print(not_exists)'
```

Same happens if we use the "db.doEval(my_js)" method in Java and we put the content of "error_test.js" file into the "my_js" variable: The mapreduce error is not detected (no excepcion is launched, no null value is returned, "ok : 1.0" appears in the response).

So my question is: How can I detect an error in the mapreduce? (both in a js file and in the doEval() method)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the return document from `db.runCommand()` into a variable and then check its `ok` value in your script - you can then throw an error or print output, etc.

```
print("it is shown");
var res = db.runCommand(
               {
                 mapReduce:  "mycol",
                 map:        function(){ print(not_exists); },
                 reduce:     function(key, values){},
                 out:        { replace: "myrescol" }
               }
             );
printjson(res);
if (res.ok == 0) {
   print("Oopsy!");
   throw("error! " + res.errmsg + " returned from mapreduce");
}
print("it is shown too (after error in mapreduce!)");
```

Comment: you can put this in a try catch block or do whatever you want once you detect an error - including returning some error code...

Comment: Thank you, it works. I didn't know that "db.runCommand()" returns a value (a json doc).  
  
In fact, I see that there is no mention of the returned value in the following pages of the manual:  

1) db.runCommand(): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/  
2) mongo Shell Methods: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/  
  
Perhaps there is a mention in some other pages, but I didn't find them. If some mongo web editor is reading this comment, please add some info on the returned value to those pages. Thank you